# Qml - Exchange date between c++ class and class created by QmlRegisterType

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have the following question regards qml object loaded with qml `Loader` `(setSource("qmlObject.qml")).`

In `qmlObject.qml` I have imported `objectClass(.h/.cpp)` created with `qmlRegisterType`, thus when I launch `loader.setSource("qmlObject.qml")` command an instance of `objectClass(.h/.cpp)` is created.

I have other main class named `coreClass(.h/.cpp)` and I should exchange data between `objectClass(.h/.cpp)` and `coreClass(.h/.cpp)`.

What's the best practice to implement this feature in my simple qt application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

1. on C++ level, since both your objects are C++ objects, you can skip using QML as an intermediator and communicate directly. Presumably your core class will be one for the whole application, so you can expose it as a static member pointer  to the core in your object class. Therefore all object class instances will have access to it.
2. on QML level, by exposing the core class to QML as a context property, or preferably as a singleton, because the latter is the most efficient way. Then you can use its properties, signals and slots (but not pure public C++ stuff) in the form of a defined functional interface.

The first approach will be much faster performance wise, and will use less memory, the downside is you will have to recompile the C++ code on every change.

The second approach will limit the interaction to what is visible in QML, which is properties, signals, slots, and functions that have been marked as invokable. It will be slower and use more memory, but on the upside you won't have to recompile, so prototyping is much more rapid.

Often such interactions will be GUI based, so the overhead will not really matter, as the user doesn't interact with the GUI thousands of times per second. If efficiency is key, you can prototype using the second approach and get things running faster, and when you are done simply port the code to the first solution.

It is also important to mention that when you do C++ to QML integration, the correct way would be to have the C++ stuff exposed to QML and use it from QML. You should never ever have to reach from C++ to arbitrary stuff in QML, this is an indication of wrong design.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily exchange data between c++ classes with SIGNAL and SLOT mechanism.
just pass pointer of coreClass to objectClass and connect signal and slots.

Comment: But the instane of objectClass is generate from qml Loader, not from coreClass. From coreClass I don't know what is the relative objectClass to exchange slots and signals.

Comment: I don't know what mean's: ' instane of objectClass is generate from qml Loader'. but you can declare objectClass and coreClass in main() function, then pass them to qml. on that way you can pass pointers to each other.